# Laravel 404's on Pages other than root ('/')

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I've installed Laravel 5.0 (standard composer install) on a shared web server running PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.2. All required modules are enabled (OpenSSL, mod_rewrite, Tokenizer, json, etc).

Going to `'*$servername*.ca/*$username*/'` shows me the splash page for Laravel, as does `'*$servername*.ca/*$username*/index.php'`. However, trying to go to the default demo routes (`'*$servername*.ca/*$username*/home'`, for example) results in a 404 page. It does this for welcome and home. `AllowOverride` is set to `All` and .htaccess files seem to be working (tested w/ a 301 redirect, they are being called). `*$servername*.ca/*username*/index.php/home` also returns a 404, which seems to show it is something other than .htaccess/pretty URLs issues. I seem to be completely unable to get routing to work correctly with anything other than the root directory (default splash page).

Comment: did you checked laravel log?

Comment: The Laravel logs are empty.